# IP Fragmentation with Jumbo frames

Tags: linux, networking, ip, aws

Is it possible to enable IP fragmentation for packet size greater than 9k when the mtu is configured as 9k? If yes, how can this be achieved in Linux?

Comment: Do you mean 'packet size smaller than 9k'? Packets larger than 9k (or larger than the PATH MTU) will get fragmented anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes

The function `ip_do_fragment` will need to be adjusted in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/`

*Refer to the following documents:*

*https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/ipv4/ip_output.c*
*https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/ipv4/ip_output.c*